# Laravel 5 - How to insert rows to multiple tables on user registration

Tags: php, laravel-5

How would I insert rows to multiple tables when a user gets registered.

I have the basic Laravel user table. I also have a businesses table (id, business_name) and a usersbusinesses table (id, user_id, business_id)

First, I need to create (db insert) the user and get its generated id value.

Then, I need to create (db insert) the business and get its generated id value.

Finally, I need to create (db insert) a row in the usersbusinesses table using the values above (user_id and business_id)

I know I’m going to have to modify the app/Services/Registrar.php file, I just don’t know how to tackle this. Current code only inserts to users table:

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do more, it's as simple as adding to that create function you just pasted.

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration and do more.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
public function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $business = Business::create([
        'name' => 'best business ever'
    ]);

    $business->owners()->sync([$user->id]);

    return $user;

}
```

For the second-to-last part with:

```
$business->owners()->sync([$user->id]);
```

You should read about Eloquent relationships [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships).

Because you're putting together this many commands, I would suggest reading into Jobs/Commands for Laravel. They're mentioned in the [Queues section](http://laravel.com/docs/master/queues) of Laravel docs.

**Update on how to add the owners() method.**

Business.php model:

```
/**
 * Owners of the business.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function owners()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'userbusinesses');
}
```

Similarly in your Users.php model:

```
/**
 * Business this person owns.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function businesses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'userbusinesses');
}
```

However, my recommendation would be to stay inline with standards and rename your pivot table to business_user, in which case you wouldn't need the second argument in belongsToMany.

Also note that I changed the command for saving to sync. I didn't realize it was a many-to-many the first time.

Comment: Thanks Suhaib Malik. I've copied your code but i'm getting the following error: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1999: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::owner()  I've read about the many to many relationships, and the third (table) i've created physically (usersbusinesses). The documentation explains the pivot table concept, is that what I should be using? Do I need my third table to be declared physically? Thanks

Comment: @user3489502 You need to have in your Model some method that relates the business to the users via an owner relationship. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, it's a many-to-many relation. Is this case, businesses represents business locations, and users are workers that can work at many different locations. That's excellent, thank so much, it worked!!! Missing ;  after sync though. So if I called my pivot table user_business or business_user, I wouldn't need   , 'userbusinesses'  as a second argument after belongsToMany. Laravel 5 rocks!  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user3489502 Most welcome! I've fixed the missing semicolon.